# How to prevent Django serializer get method executing multiple times

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have a serializer making calls to other serializers in order to produce one Article object containing all data required for the frontend.

Everything works as expected except the `get_sentiment()` method is called multiple times and I can't figure out why.

I tried to copy the behaviour from the `Tag` serializer, which produces one list containing all of the tags required. For some reason the `article_sentiment` field produces multiple lists.

If there is any insight on why DRF is producing the behaviour it'll be much appreciated.

Here are the serializers.

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'tag',
        )
        model = Tag
        
       
class SentimentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    sentiment=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta: 
        fields = (
            'sentiment',
        )
        model = Reaction
        
    def get_sentiment(self, obj):
        likes = Reaction.objects.filter(article_id=obj.article_id, sentiment=1).count()
        dislikes = Reaction.objects.filter(article_id=obj.article_id, sentiment=2).count()
        if likes + dislikes == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            percent = (likes / (likes + dislikes)) * 100
            print(obj.article_id.title + str(percent))
            items = [likes, dislikes, percent]
            return items
            
    


"""
Gets the full details of an Article
"""
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    article_tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    article_sentiment = SentimentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'content',
            'article_tags',
            'pub_date',
            'preview_image',
            'author',
            'author_profile_name',
            'article_sentiment',
        )
        model = Article
```

Here is the ouput
[image: output of API call]

thank you

Comment: Following DRF documentation on [how to deal with nested objects](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects) remove the `many=True` from your 'article_sentiment' field serializer.

Comment: @Niko i tried that. It throws an error `'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'article_id'` because I'm passing in a queryset with multiple objects.

Comment: This is expected, because each article's `article_sentiment` object will be represented by `SentimentSerializer`

Comment: @BrianDestura I didn't see why the behaviour should be any different to the `tag` field so for me it was unexpected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the SerializerMethodField into ArticleSerializer:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'tag',
        )
        model = Tag

"""
Gets the full details of an Article
"""
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    article_tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    sentiment = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'content',
            'article_tags',
            'pub_date',
            'preview_image',
            'author',
            'author_profile_name',
            'sentiment',
        )
        model = Article

    def get_sentiment(self, obj):
        likes = Reaction.objects.filter(article_id=obj.id, sentiment=1).count()
        dislikes = Reaction.objects.filter(article_id=obj.id, sentiment=2).count()
        if likes + dislikes == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            percent = (likes / (likes + dislikes)) * 100
            print(obj.title + str(percent))
            items = [likes, dislikes, percent]
            return items
```

Comment: I didn't know serializers could be mixed like that, you learn something new everyday! Thank you